# How to animate these bird wings

Tags: modeling

So basically I want to be able to rotate my bird wings, but not the part of the bird wing that is touching the bird itself, if that makes sense. So, the end of the bird wings will move down and up but the body part of the bird wings will not move at all.
[image]

As you can see below, when I rotate the wing the top goes with it so it does not rotate properely.
[image]

How can I do this to animate the bird wing????

Answer (score 1):

Set up a bone that only effects part of the wing and animate the bone so it moves the wing up and down. There are many tutorials showing how to use bones, but really select the faces that you want to move than assign them to the bone. By moving the bone, parts of the mesh move, but not all of it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I will be sure to have a look into bones @snipers500